# What is the best way to use SVN in Visual Studio 2010 solution

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn

Can anyone recommend the best way to use version control system in Visual Studio 2010.
I'm currently working on a asp.net mvc 2 web application and want to use version control system.

A SVN repository has been setup, and internaly in my company they use Tortoise. I have no issues in using Tortoise, but I wondered if there was a plugin or better way of using svn with Visual Studio.

Best practices, recommendations on other tools (ex: ankhsvn) are all welcome.

Comment: What are you looking for above what TortoiseSVN already gives you? Is there some area where it doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Tortoise is indeed giving me what I want, but as I'm quite new to Visual Studio, I was wondering if there where any good tools that work within visual studio and not on the file system.

Comment: I first wanted to upvote Greg's comment - but your reasoning seems perfectly valid Kenneth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Visual Studio SVN Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372687/good-visual-studio-svn-tool)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) or [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) to integrate into Visual Studio.

Comment: visualSVN is paying and AnkhSVN isn't, but are current versions equals in what they can/do? Otherwise I would go for AnkhSVN for sure.

Comment: I haven't tried AnkhSVN so I can't compare them. VisualSVN uses TortoiseSVN for all the work while AnkhSVN doesn't. I've read  that AnkhSVN is faster than VisualSVN but I do not know if that's true or not. One disadvantage of AnkhSVN is that it does not support bugtraq properties so you might not be able to integrate it with the bug tracking tool you are using.

Comment: Interesting you say that, at the moment I'm not using a bug tracking tool but also planning on using one, but any recommendations on how to do bugtracking with ankhsvn are welcome.

Comment: AnkhSVN does support bugtraq properties, and also has support for custom plugins for bugtrackers

Comment: @Sander - Looks like I mixed it with IBugTraqProvider which according to http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-ankhsvn-general/suggestions/97648-ibugtraqprovider?ref=title is not supported. What do you mean by "custom plugins for bugtrackers"?

Comment: See http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/IssueTrackerIntegration for the full integration. bugtraq properties need to be set at the project root, ie the SCC Binding Path in File -> Subversion -> Change Source Control

Answer (score 4):

Tortoise SVN works on the file system, whereas Ankh SVN adds similar functionality to the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

For this reason, I am currently using both.

Answer (score 3):

In my company we are using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) . It has the advantage over TortoiseSVN when adding new files to the VS project as it automatically adds them. To my experience it is easy to forget when using Tortoise from the explorer.